# foursquare connect with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, foursquare

is it possible to use the facebook connect on the foursquare connect? I mean on the connect page in foursquare you can connect via facebook, is it possible from a custom code in php?

Answer (score 0):

If the user you want to connect to your app has a Facebook account linked to their Foursquare account, they will be able to login through Facebook. Assuming this user isn't logged in, they will be prompted to log in when trying to connect with your app. Our login screen allows them to login through Facebook: http://cl.ly/image/3h3o2n1e1m1c

Comment: thanks for the answer , but going through 

https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=URl,

 the facebook connect button doesn't show up , it warns the user about the informations the application can collect and propose to create a account at the bottom or log in 

I may be wrong in the link or I don't get something

Comment: If you click "Log in" at the bottom it should take you to the previous screen I showed where they can log in with Facebook

Comment: actually no :x that's the problem, i have the page https://foursquare.com/touch/login?etc

Comment: Ah, got it, sorry I didn't realize you were trying to build a mobile app. If you're building something native, good news is that we've launched native auth recently to make this process _much_ easier. It allows your users go log in through their existing Foursquare app, which can use Facebook login. We support [Android](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth) and [iOS](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-ios-oauth). If you're building a mobile WebView-only app, unfortunately there's no support for Facebook login =\